# Find indices of non-zero elements from [1,2,0,0,4,0] in julia and create an Arrray with them

Tags: julia

I know there is a function that does this, for example:

```
A = [1,2,0,0,4,0]
find(A)

 3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 5
```

I am trying to do it on my own way, however, I am stuck here

```
for i=1:endof(A)
   if A[i] != 0
      []
   end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more where your problem is? Are you looking for `push!`? You can also have a look at the source code of `find` with `@less find(A)`.

Comment: I rather wish the community was less hasty to downvote new members. @user7546279, choose a nickname and we will love you more. And check out https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia

Comment: `B = A[A .!= 0]` also works (thanks @Ismael-VC)

Comment: Actually `B = A[A .!=0]` is not what I was looking for. What that does is to exclude the zero elements. What I wanted to do is to create an array with the indices of the non-zero elements, not with the non-zero elements. My answer below is also not correct. The desired output should be `[1,2,5]` which correspond to the positions of `1` `2` and `4`.  Sorry because I have noticed the question is so confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one alternative:

```
function myfind(c)
    a = similar(c, Int)
    count = 1
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(c)
        a[count] = i
        count += (c[i] != zero(eltype(c)))
    end
    return resize!(a, count-1)
end
```

It actually outperformed `find` for all the cases I tested, though for the very small example vector you posted, the difference was negligible. There is perhaps some performance advantage to avoiding the branch and dynamically growing the index array.

Comment: you could call `countnz` on the array `a` to get the number `n` of nonzeroes in the array, and then preallocate `a` with the correct dimension.

Comment: Sure, but then you have to pass over the array an extra time, which seems like wasted effort. It would be twice the work, essentially.

Comment: I guess that it depends on the particular aspect of performance that you wish to optimize. my suggestion reflects my preference for minimizing memory transactions. `countnz` allocates no memory, and using it to preallocate `a` uses only the memory necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I have notice that the question is really confusion (because is poorly formulated, sorry about that). Therefore, there are two possible answers: one is `[1,2,4]`which is an array with the non-zero elements; the other is `[1,2,5]` which is an array of the indices of the non-zero elements.

Let´s begin with the first option

```
A = [1,2,0,0,4,0]
B = []

for i=1:endof(A)
    if A[i] != 0
        push!(B,i)
    end
end
println(B)
```

The output is `Any[1,2,5]`

However, the type is not the one I wanted. Using `typeof(B)` it shows `Array{Any,1}` so I added this code:

```
B = Array{Int64}(B)
println(B)
typeof(B)
```

And the result is the desired

```
[1,2,5]
Array{Int64,1}
```

To improve its efficiency, following with the recommendations in the comments, I have specified the type of B with the `eltype()` function before the loop as follows:

```
A1 = [1,2,0,0,4,0] #The default type is Array{Int64,1}
B1 = eltype(A1)[] #Define the type of the 0 element array B with the type of A
#B1 = eltype(typeof(A))[] this is also valid
for i=1:endof(A1)
    if A1[i] != 0
        push!(B1::Array{Int64,1},i::Int64)
    end
end
println(B1)
typeof(B1)
```

Then, the output is again the desired

```
[1,2,5]
Array{Int64,1}
```

The simplest way of doing this is using the function `find()`. However, since I´m a beginner, I wanted to do it in another way. However, there is another alternative provided by @DNF that outperform `find()` for the cases he has tested it (see below answers).

The second option, which creates an output matrix with the non-zero elements has been provided by other users (@Harrison Grodin and @P i) in this discussion.

Thanks all of you for the help!

Comment: To get the correct type from the beginning, you can use `B = eltype(A)[]`. Eventually have a look at http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/performance-tips/. In particular, doing things in the global scope is slow.

Comment: Thank you again, these kind of things help me a lot.

Comment: Note that you don't need to reassign the result of `push!(B,...)` back to `B`. That '!' signifies that the first parameter is modified.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here.

Using the strategy you started with, you can use `push!` inside the `for` loop.

```
julia> B = Int[]
0-element Array{Int64,1}

julia> for element = A
           if element != 0
               push!(B, element)
           end
       end

julia> B
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

You can also opt to use short-circuit evaluation.

```
julia> for element = A
           element != 0 && push!(B, element)
       end

julia> for element = A
           element == 0 || push!(B, element)
       end
```

Both `filter` and list comprehensions are valid, as well!

```
julia> B = [element for element = A if element != 0]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4

julia> filter(n -> n != 0, A)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

---

*Edit:* Thanks to the OP's comment, I have realized that the desired result is the *indices* of the nonzero elements, not the elements themselves. This can be achieved simply with the following. :)

```
julia> find(A)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 5
```

Comment: The thing is that I have notice that the question is not too much clear. What I want is an array containing the indices of the non-zero elements, not an array of the non-zero elements. However, thank you so much! this is so useful.

Comment: @Pau Ah, I see! I have updated my response to include a solution for finding the indices. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just because I don't see a simple solution posted here, this is approach I took to the same problem. I think it is the simplest and most elegant solution. Hope this closes the thread!

```
julia> A = [1,2,0,0,4,0];
julia> findall(!iszero,A)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really easy:

```
np.nonzero([1,2,0,0,4,0])
```